# How to Setup for Recurring Giving

Tags: civicontribute, recurring-contributions

Hi I am thinking about using CiviCRM and we are implementing a recurring giving program. How would I set up CiviCRM to track recurring monthly, bi-monthly, quarterly or annual donor contributions and send them reminders that their credit card is going to be charged?

Answer (score 4):

The answer depends on your payment processor, but here's the general plan:

- Contact your payment processor and inform them that you want ARB (Automated Recurring Billing) added to your account. Most payment processors will add an additional monthly charge (around $10-20/month). Some (like iATS Payments) do not.
- Most payment processors (e.g. Authorize.Net, PayPal) will send a notification to a predetermined URL when they process a payment.  Instructions are here for [PayPal](http://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/PayPal+Website+Payments+Standard+and+Recurring+Contributions) and [Authorize](http://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/Authorize.net+Configuration).
- Other payment processors (e.g. iATS Payments) store a token in CiviCRM.  CiviCRM submits the token on a regular basis to process a payment.
- On any contribution page, go to the **Configure menu > Contribution Amounts** and check the box labeled "Recurring Contributions".

You can configure your options from there.  Bi-monthly and quarterly transactions are possible by specifying recurring intervals.  I've been commissioned to write an extension to add "quarterly" as an option without using intervals, but it's not written yet!

Comment: jon - did the quarterly extension happen?

Comment: also am i right that there is no way in UI currently to stipulate the # of months, ie it is either 'monthly' or it is 'let user put in any number of months'

Comment: @petednz-fuzion Nope on the quarterly extension, you're right that there's no place in the UI to stipulate the # of months.

Comment: thx for confirmation