# Recurring Contribution marked incomplete and no receipt sent but card is charged

Tags: drupal, civicontribute, recurring-contributions

We tested a few recurring donations and while our payment gateway, Authorize.net, shows that the transactions were completed, the user does not receive a receipt. Furthermore, their contribution is marked in their contact record as pending/incomplete. Also, the transaction details are not reported in the CiviCRM. It reports "no payments found".

We are on CiviCRM 4.7.15. Is there something I need to set up? This is the first time we've attempted to use recurring contribution feature.

I've already gone through the steps in [this post](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/7258/how-to-setup-for-recurring-giving).

I tailed the ConfigAndLog for errors during a transaction and nothing was reported.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There needs to be a silent post URL inputted into Authorize.net

> CiviCRM will need to be notified of the success of recurring
>   contributions via a Silent Post URL. Within CiviCRM, get the ID number
>   of your payment processor by looking at the URL of the form for
>   editing your payment processor: it should read "&id=" followed by a
>   number. That number is your ID. Within Authorize.net, go to **Account >
>   Settings > Silent Post URL** (within the Transaction Format Settings
>   section). On that page, enter the URL (the following examples are for
>   payment processor ID 2):

```
Drupal: https://yoursite.org/civicrm/payment/ipn/2

Joomla!: https://yoursite.org/index.php?option=com_civicrm&task=civicrm/payment/ipn/2

WordPress: https://yoursite.org/?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm/payment/ipn/2
```

> If you fail to do this, one-time contributions will succeed normally,
>   and recurring contributions will be processed successfully by
>   Authorize.net, but the contribution status will be stuck at Pending.

[image]

Source: https://docs.civicrm.org/sysadmin/en/latest/setup/payment-processors/authorize-net/